# What's a better way to consolidate code in a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

How do I consolidate the following code in a loop? My goal is to repeat the classes .node and .visual-content with a consecutive number at the end of the class.

```
$s(".node1").hover(function () {
$s(".visual-content1").fadeIn("slow");
 $s(".visual-content2").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content3").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content4").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content5").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content6").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content7").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content8").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content9").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content10").fadeOut();
});

$s(".node2").hover(function () {
$s(".visual-content2").fadeIn();
 $s(".visual-content1").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content3").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content4").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content5").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content6").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content7").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content8").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content9").fadeOut();
 $s(".visual-content10").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: A for loop with [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: That's really a misuse of classes, which by definition are sets of like things. Just use one class name for this. Chances are you can use some other technique to identify individual elements. In short, you're asking the wrong question. Post your markup for better suggestions.

Comment: It's probably a mistake to have all these classes with numbers suffixed onto them. If the elements are a contiguous range of elements within a container, you should probably just find them using a common selector and loop through them. If their order in the DOM doesn't match the order in which you want to traverse them, you should have a separate marker (like a `data` attribute) that allows you to impose an order before traversing them.

Comment: No loop necessary `$('[class^="visual-content"]').*`

Comment: Is `$s()` a jQuery reference? If so, please tag the question as jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do two loops: An outer loop for the .nodes, and an inner loop for the visual contents. That would work like this:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    $s(".node"+i).hover(function(){
    $s(".visual-content"+i).fadeIn("slow");
    for(let j = 1; j <= 10; j++){
        if(j != i){
        $s(".visual-content"+j).fadeOut();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Although the comments are right, you might want to check if there's a better solution.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use classes and data attributes and ignore all the copy paste code.

```js
$(".node").on("mouseenter", function () {
  var toggles = $(this).data('toggles')
  $('.content').not(toggles).fadeOut()
  $(toggles).fadeIn()
})
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="node" data-toggles="#content1">One</li>
  <li class="node" data-toggles="#content2">Two</li>
  <li class="node" data-toggles="#content3">Three</li>
</ul>

<div id="content1" class="content">One Content</div>
<div id="content2" class="content">Two Content</div>
<div id="content3" class="content">Three Content</div>
```